# Differential Equation Approach?

Tags: calculus

$$y~ dy+(2+x^2-y^2)dx$$

I try to solve this equation by putting standard form but becomes more challenge . So your answer is helpful

Comment: Is it equal to $0$ on the right hand side?

Comment: @projectilemotion: Likely is - it was unreadable before the edit - so maybe some stuff is missing.

Comment: it is a Bernoulli equation

Comment: see also here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/bernoulli.aspx

Answer (score 0):

$y\,dy+(2+x^2-y^2)\,dx=0$
$y\,dy=-(2+x^2-y^2)\,dx$
$\frac{y\,dy}{dx}=-2-x^2+y^2$
$yy'-y^2=-2-x^2$

Use the following substitution: $v=y^2$.  This gives us $v'=2yy'$

Now you have $\frac{1}{2}v'-v=-2x-x^2.$  It should be easy to take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on emka's answer:
\begin{align*}
y\,dy+\left(2+x^2-y^2\right)dx=0\\
y\,dy=-\left(2+x^2-y^2\right)dx\\
y\frac{dy}{dx}=-2-x^2+y^2\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left(y^2\right)-y^2=-2-x^2
\end{align*}
Make a substitution $v=y^2$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dv}{dx}-v=-2-x^2\\
\frac{d^3v}{dx^3}-\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}=-2\\
\frac{\frac{d^3v}{dx^3}}{\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}-2}=1\\
\int\frac{1}{v''-2}\,dv''=\int1\,dx\\
\ln\left(v''-2\right)=x+C_1
\end{align*}
Let $\exp(C_1)=c_1$:
\begin{align*}
v''=c_1e^x+2\\
v'=c_1e^x+2x+c_2\\
v=c_1e^x+x^2+c_2x\\
y^2=c_1e^x+x^2+c_2x
\end{align*}
Plugging back into the equation $\frac{d}{dx}\left(y^2\right)-y^2=-2-x^2$:
\begin{align*}
c_1e^x+2x+c_2-c_1e^x-x^2-c_2x=2-x^2\\
c_2-x^2+\left(2-c_2\right)x=2-x^2
\end{align*}
Ergo $c_2=2$, yielding the following solution:
$$y^2=c_1e^x+x^2+2x$$